# Array sorting encase sorting is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm trying to sort the data in the following order but unfortunately it is not working.

Expert advise please?

**Input is**

```
 [/,2,$,3,B,a,A,arrow, ba, bs]
```

**Expected output is**

```
$
/
2
3
A,
a,
arrow,
B,
ba,
bs
```

Here my try

```
var unifiedElements = ["/","2","$","3","B","a","A","arrow", "ba", "bs"];

 unifiedElements.sort(function(a, b) {
                            return sortvalue(a,b)                            
                        });  

 function sortvalue(a, b) {
                let g = /^[A-Z]$/i;
                if (!g.test(a) || !g.test(b)) return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
                let r = a.toString().toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toString().toLowerCase());
                return r ? r : b.localeCompare(a);
            }


console.log(unifiedElements);

**Result is** 
["$", "/", "2", "3", "A", "a", "B", "arrow", "ba", "bs"]

**Expected is** 
["$", "/", "2", "3", "A", "a", "arrow", "B", "ba", "bs"]
```

Comment: Why is that the expected output?

Comment: Where's the code that you're using to sort this data? You should add it to your question.

Comment: one thing you'll struggle with ... if you want case insensitive result there's no guaranteed order of 'a' and 'A' for example

Comment: @JaromandaX isn't it simple: if lowercase(x) !== lowercase(y) - compare lowercased, otherwise order upper case first.

Comment: so... calling .sort didn't work, eh? Put bounty on the question if you want someone to write the code for you. Otherwise, please provide your sorting method so we could help you with adjustments.

Comment: @zerkms - hmmm, I was looking at trying to make it simple using `localeCompare` - sometimes the simplest answers are NOT better :p

Comment: You can use `Array.sort` with a `compareFunction` ( see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Parameters)

Comment: Updated my post with my code try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
["$", "/", "2", "3", "A", "B", "a", "arrow", "ba", "bs"]
 .sort((a,b) => a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1)
```

You need to compare lowercased symbols to get the expected result. As mentioned in comments, you have to use a compare function that can be passed to Array.prototype.sort method as a first parameter.